# How can I implode an array while skipping empty array items?

Tags: php, implode

Perl's `join()` ignores (skips) empty array values; PHP's `implode()` does not appear to.

Suppose I have an array:

```
$array = array('one', '', '', 'four', '', 'six');
implode('-', $array);
```

yields:

```
one---four--six
```

instead of (IMHO the preferable):

```
one-four-six
```

Any other built-ins with the behaviour I'm looking for? Or is it going to be a custom jobbie?

Comment: You're wrong about Perl's behaviour. `join` doesn't skip undefined elements. In fact, they result in a warning. `$a[0]="a"; $a[2]="c"; say join "-",@a;` displays `Use of uninitialized value within @a in join or string` and `a--c`. One can use `join '-', grep !defined, ...` to skip undefined values. `grep !length,` will do empty strings.

Answer (score 247, accepted):

You can use [**`array_filter()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

> If no *callback* is supplied, all entries of *input* equal to **`FALSE`** (see [converting to boolean](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)) will be removed.

```
implode('-', array_filter($array));
```

Obviously this will not work if you have `0` (or any other value that evaluates to `false`) in your array and you want to keep it. But then you can provide your own callback function.

Comment: Would that mean that `false`, and `0` are also thrown out?

Comment: @maz: Yes, but you can always provide your own callback. `empty`, as you use it, will also treat `0` and `false` as `false` (and remove it) btw.

Comment: +1, but it has to be mentioned, that `array_filter()` by default filters off every `false`, `null`, empty string ('') and `0`.

Comment: @Tadeck: Yes, just follow the link in the quote. Even more values are considered as `false`: empty array, `0.0` and `"0"`.

Comment: @Felix: I knew it - just wanted to stress it for people new in PHP ;) Anyway: thank you

Comment: Nice trick - didn't know array_filter can work without callback :)

Answer (score 9):

I suppose you can't consider it built in (because the function is running with a user defined function), but you could always use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).
Something like:

```
function rempty ($var)
{
    return !($var == "" || $var == null);
}
$string = implode('-',array_filter($array, 'rempty'));
```

Comment: Using `empty` has the same effect as passing no callback at all. *Edit: You have to negate the return value. Otherwise only empty elements will be returned ;) (actually using `empty` as you did before was also wrong)*

Comment: Yeah, that's backward. But you gave me the right idea `implode('-', array_filter($ary, create_function('$a', 'return $a!="";')));`

Answer (score 8):

To remove `null`, `false`, `empty` string but preserve `0`, etc. use func. *'`strlen`'*

```
$arr = [null, false, "", 0, "0", "1", "2", "false"];
print_r(array_filter($arr, 'strlen'));
```

will output:

```
//Array ( [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 1 [6] => 2 [7] => false )
```

Answer (score 3):

How you should implement you filter only depends on what you see as "empty".

```
function my_filter($item)
{
    return !empty($item); // Will discard 0, 0.0, '0', '', NULL, array() of FALSE
    // Or...
    return !is_null($item); // Will only discard NULL
    // or...
    return $item != "" && $item !== NULL; // Discards empty strings and NULL
    // or... whatever test you feel like doing
}

function my_join($array)
{
    return implode('-',array_filter($array,"my_filter"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = ["one", NULL, "two", NULL, "three"];
$string = implode("-", array_diff($array, [NULL]));
echo $string;
```

Returns `one-two-three`

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I can find, I'd say chances are, there isn't really any way to use a PHP built in for that. But you could probably do something along the lines of this:

```
function implode_skip_empty($glue,$arr) {
      $ret = "";
      $len = sizeof($arr);
      for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++) {
          $val = $arr[$i];    
          if($val == "") {
              continue;
          } else {
            $ret .= $arr.($i+1==$len)?"":$glue;
          }
      }
      return $ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$result = array();

foreach($array as $row) { 
   if ($row != '') {
   array_push($result, $row); 
   }
}

implode('-', $result);
```

Answer (score -1):

`array_fileter()` seems to be the accepted way here, and is probably still the most robust answer tbh.

However, the following will also work if you can guarantee that the "glue" character doesn't already exist in the strings of each array element (which would be a given under most practical circumstances -- otherwise you wouldn't be able to distinguish the glue from the actual data in the array):

```
$array = array('one', '', '', 'four', '', 'six');
$str   = implode('-', $array);
$str   = preg_replace ('/(-)+/', '\1', $str);
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
if(isset($array))  $array = implode(",", (array)$array);
```

Comment: You might want to use isset() to prevent warnings.

Comment: I'm not sure how `isset()` or casting the input array as `array` addresses any of the concerns of the original post?

Comment: This is not a solution. Casting to (array) does not remove empty items from the array.